# How to change the background image of a button dynamically?

Tags: android, button

I have a `Button` name is `Start` actually `Start` is a image which i have placed in my button  as a background `android:background="@drawable/btn_stop` what i want to do is By pressing the `Start`  button it should replace the `Start` image with `Stop` I am able to do it in Java Code by using `btnStartStop.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_stop);` but i want to do it `XML` by using `selector` i have used this code

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button_start_stop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_selector"/>
```

Here **btn_selector** is `XML` file which i have created inside the `drawable` folder
which contain
**btn_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_stop"
          android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_start"/>
</selector>
```

but its only creating a hovering effect for ex:it only showing `Stop` when i am pressing the `Start` for a second and then after its showing `Start`.

**Note:I Don't want to use Toggle Button**

Comment: for that you can use toggle button,because according to drawable your button image change in pressed state

Comment: But i don't wanna use toggle button.

Comment: @user2295109 use custom chekbox or radio button..!

Answer (score 1):

Your selector should be like,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/switch_on" />
        <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/switch_on" />
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/switch_off" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

And your listener should be like,

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    if(button.isSelected())
                     {               
                        button.setSelected(false);
                     }
                    else
                     {
                        button.setSelected(true);
                     }

                }
            });
```

Comment: thanks for the answer i think it will work  hopefully let me check.

Answer (score 0):

In last version of android studio 2.2.3  this line works :

```
 DYNAMIC_ELEMENT.setBackground( getDrawable( R.drawable.circle ) );


compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 25
```

Also older versions :

```
 DYNAMIC_ELEMENT.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image_bg));
```